# When is viewWillAppear called?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

By my count, the only two instances when viewWillAppear is called is when you initialize your view controller, or when you pop off the view controller that's on top of it on the navigation stack (ie pushing the back button on the viewcontroller ahead of it). Are there any other instances when viewWillAppar is called? I don't believe it's called when the app becomes active. Interested to hear some responses on this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

viewwillappear method is called as and when the view controller's view is added to the window. ( if the view is already in the window and is hidden by another view, this method is called when the view is once again revealed). The method is a notification to the view controller that the view is about to become visible. You can override this method to make any customizations with presenting the view.

Comment: When is it added to the window, like specifically? When you initialize the viewcontroller, when you pop the viewcontroller that's on top of it off the stack and ??? That's what I'm trying to find if there are any more scenarios.

Comment: It is called when ever the view appears on the screen. Yes even when the view controller is initialized or when you navigate to the view in a stack.

Comment: I have updated to Xcode 11, after dismissing a view controller previous view controller viewWIllAppear method is not being called

Answer (score 6):

This will also be called anytime addSubView is called, with your view.